# Angular Router Navigate is Reloading Lazy Loaded Parent Components

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular7-router

I have ModuleA which is lazy loaded and have below given components and their routes;

```
path: 'JobView/:id', component: JobViewComponent, children: [
  { path : '', redirectTo: 'AppliedCandidates', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'AppliedCandidates', component: AppliedCandidatesComponent },
  { path: 'AssignCandidates', component: AssignCandidatesComponent }
]
```

Content of JobViewComponent looks like this;

```
  <div class="col-xl-3 pr-3">
    <job-detail-view> </job-detail-view>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-9 pl-3">
    <div class="portlet">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I navigate to any sibling route using router navigate, like navigating to **AppliedCandidates** by clicking on link from **AssignedCandidates** using,

```
this.router.navigate(['../AppliedCandidates'], {
      relativeTo: this.route});
```

It keeps on reloading **JobViewComponent** component as well which does not happen in eager loading case. Any help to avoid this overhead of reloading this component will be appreciated.

**Edit:**
Actually, it works but the problem is that it reloads the parent component i.e(JobViewComponent) as well which does not happen if I do not lazy load this modules. I drilled down this issue and came to know that this is happening because of some common packages prefixed with default word as shown below.
[image]

It loads two extra packages prefixed with default word. If these packages are not loaded my problem does not occur. I think this is happening because some services of Candidate Module are being used in other lazyloaded modules. Any help to get over this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
this.router.navigate(['../AppliedCandidates'], {
      relativeTo: this.route});
```

Because you are using '../', when you use '../' you are saying navigate to 'localhost:4200/AppliedCandidates' instead of navigating to 'localhost:4200/JobView/:id/AppliedCandidates' as you want.

If you want to navigate relative to the url where you are at that moment (localhost:4200/JobView/:id) in this case, you have to use: './' that means: from the url add this path ('AppliedCandidates' for example) and navigate to there.

In conclusion, you have to navigate like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['./AppliedCandidates'], {
      relativeTo: this.route});
```

Try if that works.

Comment: My bad, I did not explain that the problem occurs when I navigate to **AppliedCandidates** from **AssignedCandidates** which is sibling to it. So, in this case I have to use 
`this.router.navigate(['../AppliedCandidates'], { relativeTo: this.route});`
 instead of using 
`this.router.navigate(['./AppliedCandidates'], { relativeTo: this.route});`
 because it starts giving error that route localhost:4200/JobView/:id/AssignedCandidates/AppliedCandidates does not exist which is actually right. Please see the edited explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I don't understand why `this.router.navigate(['../AppliedCandidates'], { relativeTo: this.route})` doesn't work from AssignedCandidates.
Could you upload the code to https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: Actually, it works but the problem is that it reloads the parent component i.e(JobViewComponent) as well which does not happen if do not lazy load this modules. I drilled down this issue and came to know that this is happening because of some common packages prefixed with default word. please see edited question for further clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have fixed my issue by separating my shared components

Comment: Your welcome, it's great to hear that you fixed the issue.